# Lua in Visual Basic.net

Tags: vb.net, scripting, lua, embedded-language

I'm trying to just get a VB.net app to be able to execute a lua script in a external file, and be able to add some functions to lua too, To do this I have this code:

```
Imports LuaInterface
Public Class Form1
Public luascripting As New Lua()
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
luascripting.RegisterFunction("DisplayText", Me, Me.GetType().GetMethod("DisplayText"))
luascripting.DoFile("script.lua")
End Sub
End Class
```

But it errors on the register function, saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Do you know of a example VB.net project that uses lua? Or know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registering a function but you forgot to write it.  Paste this into your form code:

```
Public Sub DisplayText()
    MsgBox("Works")
End Sub
```

Comment: AHA! The problem was that it wasn't a public sub! (I did have it though, I just didn't put my entire code.)

Comment: No, the real problem beyond the poor code snippet is that you forgot to specify the BindingFlags for GetMethod().  You need BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public.  For the record.